# C sscanf errror in reading 32 bit integer

Tags: c, string, scanf

```
   char *pStrBuffer;

   unsigned char data;
   unsigned int Address;

   /* pStrBuffer reading from a file data in file of the form 
     WriteByte(0xDE04,0x20)
     WriteByte(0xFE08,0x50) ....

    */
   /* in a loop */
   sscanf(pStrBuffer,"%x%x",&Address,&data);
```

Compiler is gnu gcc 4.5 in Windows XP
However the Value read for Address is 0xDE00 instead of 0xDE04 ? why is that so although value of data is read correctly.
 I also tried to use %lx and %hx respectively but of no use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read a single unsigned byte, use the `%hhx` modifier.  `%hx` is for an `unsigned short`, `%x` is for an `unsigned int`, `%lx` is for an `unsigned long`, and `%llx` is for an `unsigned long long.